# connection reset by peer while accessing the rest API of elasticsearch running on ubuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

Iam running elasticsearch on Ubuntu VM running on top of the Oracle virtual box. I have configured port forwarding to the VM on virtual box. The local port 9201 is forwarding to the VM port 9200. As you know 9200 is the rest API port of elasticsearch. Now when i try to access the rest api of the elasticsearch from my local terminal as follows:

```
curl -vv -XGET 127.0.0.1:9201 

I get  the following:

Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
* Rebuilt URL to: 127.0.0.1:9201/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 9201 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:9201
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Now i have also set up tcpdump on the server(VM running the elasticsearch) and it dumps the following when it receives the request:

```
12:40:39.540317 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 34977, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 44)
    10.0.2.2.44152 > 10.0.2.15.9200: Flags [S], cksum 0x14d9 (correct), seq 4006784001, win 65535, options [mss 1460], length 0
12:40:39.540346 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58786, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    10.0.2.15.9200 > 10.0.2.2.44152: Flags [R.], cksum 0x2c82 (correct), seq 0, ack 4006784002, win 0, length 0
```

But when SSH to the virtual machine (serer running elasticsearch) and do the following:

```
curl -XGET 127.0.0.1:9200 

{
  "name" : "jEukiTt",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "xk6SzW0kT_WFSXnm-0u4Hw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.1.2",
    "build_hash" : "5b1fea5",
    "build_date" : "2018-01-10T02:35:59.208Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.1.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I get the desired response as above .So as i can see the server(VM running elasticsearch) receives the request but its sending the reset signal back to the client  and just suppressing the request to elasticsearch rest API. How to resolve this.

Please reply thanks in advance
Santhosh

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when I tried to run elasticsearch as a docker container, and managed to fix it by adding the following line in the `elasticsearch.yml` file

`network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0`

Or you can add it as an environment variable in docker-compose file like this:

```
environment:
    - network.bind_host=0.0.0.0
```

What this does is it binds the elasticsearch rest server to 0.0.0.0 which allows it to accept connection coming in to any IP

Comment: Thank you! this worked. As of Elasticsearch 7.14.1 & docker-compose file version 3.8 I had to add `network.host: 0.0.0.0` to my `elasticsearch.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that without firewall 0.0.0.0 is open to the internet.

On some distributions/versions docker will come up with a bridge network on something like 172.17.0.1. That interface is still private/local. In that case set your bind to that interface and use the IP...

In the YAML, put it like:

```
ports:
  - "172.17.0.1:9200:9200"
```

and it will work, ie:

```
[joeuser@server]~/elastic% netstat -an | egrep 9200
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:9200         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
[joeuser@server]~/elastic%
```

and:

```
[joeuser@server]~/elastic% curl -X GET "172.17.0.1:9200/_cat/nodes?v=true&pretty"
ip         heap.percent ram.percent cpu load_1m load_5m load_15m node.role   master name
172.19.0.2           40          93   4    1.68    1.96     1.64 cdfhilmrstw -      es02
172.19.0.4           34          93   4    1.68    1.96     1.64 cdfhilmrstw *      es01
172.19.0.3           24          93   4    1.68    1.96     1.64 cdfhilmrstw -      es03
[joeuser@server]~/elastic%
```

YMMV for the network but looking at the interfaces and routes it should be obvious.